# labelField.getWidth() returns 0? Why does this happen?

Tags: blackberry, horizontalfieldmanager

I'm working on my own custom manager, and I've gotten it complete so far, but it setsMargins using a percentage of  the screen resolution.

Here's how I call the following class:

```java
LabelIconCommandManager licm3 = new LabelIconCommandManager("Address blah bklahblah ", 0);
licm3.add(new ImageButtonField(b1, b2, b3, Field.FIELD_LEFT | ImageButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK));
```

Here's the class [I've marked in a comment where it returns 0 and where it returns 219. please tell me why this happens:

```java
public class LabelIconCommandManager extends HorizontalFieldManager implements  BCMSField
{
    LabelIconCommandManager me = this;
    EvenlySpacedHorizontalFieldManager buttonManager = new EvenlySpacedHorizontalFieldManager(0);
    LabelField labelField;
    int side = 0;
    int HPADDING = 3;
    int VPADDING = 4;
    int screenWidth = Display.getWidth();
    int labelField_width = 40;
    public LabelIconCommandManager()
    {
        this("", 0);
    }
    public LabelIconCommandManager(String label, long style)
    {
        super(USE_ALL_WIDTH| FOCUSABLE);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(new XYEdges(15, 20, 15, 20),Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "border_edit.png" )));
        this.setMargin(1,10,1,10);
        labelField = new LabelField(label,LabelField.ELLIPSIS)
        {
            public void layout(int width, int height)
            {
                // Done because otherwise ellipses dont work with labelfields
                super.layout((int)(screenWidth * 0.61), getHeight());
                setExtent((int)(screenWidth * 0.61), getHeight());
                labelField_width = labelField.getWidth();
                DisplayDialog.alert("labelField_width = " + labelField_width); // returns 219
            }
        };
        // Top Right Bottom Left
        labelField.setMargin(VPADDING, HPADDING, VPADDING, 0);
        // super because we want this horizontalfieldManager to add it
        super.add(labelField);
        super.add(buttonManager);
    }
    public void alternateConstructor(Attributes atts)
    {
        labelField = new LabelField(atts.getValue("label"), 0);
    }
    public void onFocus(int direction)
    {
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(new XYEdges(15, 20, 15, 20),Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "border_edit_select.png" )));
        // uses the same color as listStyleButtonField selections
        this.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0x186DEF));
        super.onFocus(direction);
    }
    //Invoked when a field loses the focus.
    public void onUnfocus()
    {
        //top, right,bottom,left
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(new XYEdges(15, 20, 15, 20),Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "border_edit.png" )));
        this.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.GRAY, 0));
        super.onUnfocus();
        invalidate();
    }
    // Overrride this managers add function
    public void add(Field imageButton)
    {
        // Add a button to the evenly spaced manager
        buttonManager.add(imageButton);
        // Based on how many buttons there are, set the margin of where the manager holding the buttons start [offset from labelField]
        if(buttonManager.getFieldCount() == 1)
        {
            //side = (int)(screenWidth * 0.1388);
            side = screenWidth - labelField_width - 32 - 10 - 15;
            DisplayDialog.alert("Screen Width = " + screenWidth);
            DisplayDialog.alert("labelField_width2 = " + labelField_width); // returns 0
            DisplayDialog.alert("Side = " + side);
        }
        else side = (int)(screenWidth * 0.05);
        buttonManager.setMargin(0,0,0,side);
    }
    public int getLabelWidth()
    {
        return labelField_width;
    }
}
```

Here's a picture just to be more clear:

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: How do you use this side field?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers - I will try out everything soon. I use the "side" variable to calculate the distance I will need from the end of my labelfield, to the start of my buttonManager. I've posted up a picture to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** when I ran your code, I didn't actually see `labelField_width` set to `0`.  You initialize the value to `40` in the code you posted above.  So, I do sometimes see it set to 40, or 219 (on a 360 px wide screen).

But, the problem is that I think you're trying to access the value of `labelField_width` too soon. The only place it's properly assigned is in the `layout()` method of your anonymous `LabelField`.  Just because you declare and implement the `layout()` method in line with the instantiation, doesn't mean that it's called when the `LabelField` is created.  This is actually one of the reasons I don't like anonymous classes.

Anyway, this code:

```java
LabelIconCommandManager licm3 = new LabelIconCommandManager("Address blah bklahblah ", 0); 
licm3.add(new ImageButtonField(b1, b2, b3, Field.FIELD_LEFT | ImageButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK));
```

Will first instantiate the `LabelField` (inside the `LabelIconCommandManager` constructor).  As I said, that does **not** trigger the `layout()` method.  The second line above (`add()`) will trigger your overridden method:

```java
// Overrride this managers add function 
public void add(Field imageButton) 
{
```

which is where you see the bad value for `labelField_width`.  That method gets called before `layout()`.  That's the problem.

Since it looks like you only use that width to set the `buttonManager` margin, you could just wait a little longer to do that.  If you wait until the `LabelIconCommandManager` `sublayout()` method is called, your `LabelField` will have had its `layout()` method called, and `labelField_width` assigned correctly:

```java
protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
   // make sure to call superclass method first!
   super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);

   // now, we can reliably use the label width:
   side = screenWidth - labelField_width - 32 - 10 - 15; 
   buttonManager.setMargin(0,0,0,side); 
}
```

That method goes in the `LabelIconCommandManager` class.  And then, you can remove the other place you call `buttonManager.setMargin()`.

Comment: @Eugen, Yes, I didn't mean "inline" in the same way you have the keyword `inline` in a language like C++.  But, in the general English sense, the word "inline" means "in a line", or "collinear".  So, anonymous classes are declared and defined inline with their instantiations, which is different from a normal java class, which is declared and defined somewhere else from where it's instantiated.  The problem I was pointing out is that for beginners, it can be misleading, in that it may look like the method `layout()` in this case might be called on instantiation, which of course, it's not.

Comment: @Eugen, no problem.  It was actually a great comment.  I changed the wording a little, to hopefully make clear that I'm not referring to the same `inline` concept that exists in other languages.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some brief summary from Nate post.

When you construct manager and add fields don't expect that it will be layouted correctly. Manager doesn't know the context - where it will be placed. **So layout method for field will be called only when you add his manager to the screen (when layout for manager will be also called).** And this is correct.

Move the calculation of your `side` variable to `layout` method.

If you really need `side` value before you put manager to screen. You could precalculate it by using `Field.getPrefferedWidth()` which returns meaningful values for standard fields (`getFont().getAdvance(text)` for `LabelField`, probably also with borders please check yourself). But be careful with this values.

Answer (score 1):

Please review code below. It's manager which has label and buttons. And it puts label at the left side and buttons at the right.

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Border;

import java.util.Vector;

public class TabFieldManager extends Manager {

public TabFieldManager(long style) {
    super(style);
}

protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
    LabelField label = null;

    Vector tabs = new Vector();
    int tabsWidth = 0;
    int tabHeight = 0;
    int tabPaddingTop = 0;
    int tabPaddingLeft = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < getFieldCount(); i++) {
        Field field = getField(i);
        if (field instanceof LabelField) {
            label = (LabelField) field;
        } else if (field instanceof ButtonField){
            tabs.addElement(field);

            layoutChild(field, width, height);

            int fieldwidth = field.getWidth() > 0 ? field.getWidth() : field.getPreferredWidth() ;
            tabsWidth += fieldwidth + getBorderAndPaddingWidth(field);

            int fieldHeight = field.getHeight() > 0 ? field.getHeight() : field.getPreferredHeight();
            if (fieldHeight > tabHeight) {
                tabHeight = getBorderAndPaddingHeight(field) + fieldHeight;
            }

            int fieldPaddingTop = field.getPaddingTop();
            if (fieldPaddingTop > tabPaddingTop) {
                tabPaddingTop = fieldPaddingTop;
            }

            int fieldPaddingLeft = field.getPaddingLeft();
            if (fieldPaddingLeft > tabPaddingLeft) {
                tabPaddingLeft = fieldPaddingLeft;
            }
        }
    }

    if (label != null) {
        layoutChild(label, width - tabsWidth, height);
        int y = tabHeight - label.getHeight() >> 1;
        setPositionChild(label, tabPaddingLeft , y);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tabs.size(); i++) {
        Field tabField = (Field) tabs.elementAt(i);
        setPositionChild(tabField, width - tabsWidth, getBorderAndPaddingHeight(tabField));
        tabsWidth -= tabField.getWidth() + getBorderAndPaddingWidth(tabField);
    }

    setExtent(width, tabHeight);
}

private int getBorderAndPaddingHeight( Field field ) {
    int height = field.getPaddingTop() + field.getPaddingBottom();
    Border border = field.getBorder();
    if( border != null ) {
        height += border.getTop() + border.getBottom();
    }

    return height;
}

private int getBorderAndPaddingWidth( Field field ){
    int width = field.getPaddingLeft() + field.getPaddingRight();
    Border border = field.getBorder();
    if( border != null ) {
        width += border.getLeft() + border.getRight();
    }
    return width;
}

protected int moveFocus(int amount, int status, int time) {
    if ((status & Field.STATUS_MOVE_FOCUS_VERTICALLY) == Field.STATUS_MOVE_FOCUS_VERTICALLY && amount > 0) {
        return amount;
    } else
        return super.moveFocus(amount, status, time);
}

protected int nextFocus(int amount, int axis) {
    if (amount > 0 && axis == Field.AXIS_VERTICAL)
        return -1;
    else
        return super.nextFocus(amount, axis);
}
```

}